# Display string with newline characters in GtkTextView

Tags: c, string, unicode, newline, gtktextview

I used this code to display string to a GtkTextView object:

```
btsel(database, word, meaning, 50000, &rsize); //B-tree
gtk_text_buffer_set_text(buffer, meaning, -1);
```

Problem is that it showed the entire string without parsing the newline characters, the result ended up like this:

```
Nguyễn\nAnh\nTuấn
```

At first i thought the prolem was the use of Unicode characters, so i tried using the following code to test if it was true:

```
strcpy(buffer, "Nguyễn\nAnh\nTuấn");
gtk_text_buffer_set_text(buffer, meaning, -1);
```

And this time the result was:

```
Nguyễn
Anh
Tuấn
```

After hours searching Google in vain, i ended up here. Pls help me, and thank you in advance (^^

My bad English.

Comment: You don't show what the input was in your first attempt. Is the `\n` code *literally* in there? If so, then gtk works correctly, and you have to scan for the substring `"\n"` and replace it with an actual end-of-line code before displaying.